# Outlook - send as different email, same user

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

The user has several different email aliases -- bob@company.com, fred@company.com etc, on EXCHANGE.

The user has permission for other accounts, and can send as other users, each of which has their own email address.  But no matter which email aliases she choose to send from, the mail goes out with the primary email address of that account, not the aliases she has chosen.

Is there any way to select which email address of the account is used?

Comment: POP or Exchange?

Comment: exchange, not pop

Comment: I think (not certain) for Exchange the user's main email address will be used.

Comment: @user165568 - You should [edit] your question in that case

Comment: Try the following article:   New feature (Jan 2022):   https://lazyadmin.nl/office-365/send-from-alias/

Comment: ok @Ramhound. I have capitalized the word "EXCHANGE" to make stand out better.

Comment: how did she configure the alias to send as? via *From*, *Other Email Address...*, yes?

Comment: @criztovyl , using the 'from' field in outlook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of exchange, and as far as I know, this is a limitation of the email address policy

[image]

You can use multiple email addresses to accept emails, but you can only reply to emails from the primary email address